# Java retry logic after migration or application restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am looking for a library that can retry faied jobs after server restart. For example my API expose endpoint that allow end user to upload photo and then I need asynchronusly upload this photo to third part API.

Spring Retry seemed a perfect option for me, but I can't be sure the faild job will resume after application restart. I tried to implement RetryContextCache that stores serialized objects in the database, but it does not work.

If there is any production ready library or any other way I can achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [JobRunr](https://www.jobrunr.io/en/) and [Quartz Scheduler](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) libs.

Alternatively you could just use [Spring Scheduler](https://reflectoring.io/spring-scheduler/) and check manually, if there new/unfinished jobs.